# Solve the equation for x:

Tags: logarithms

The question is 
Solve for x:
log(x^2 -12x +36) = 2

The answer given is
x = 16 or -4

Please solve it according to class 11

Comment: Please show your work and where you faced problems

Comment: The reason this question is getting down voted is because you haven't shown any effort in how you proceeded to solve the problem. Even if you blundered somewhere in the middle, it doesn't matter as long as you tried.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jhy6B78

Comment: Please have a look. I've tried but I'm getting only 16

Comment: I don't care of being down rated but please answer my question

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log(x-6)^2 = 2$$
Solved correctly till above but then you made a mistake. The correct way is as shown below:

$$\implies 2\times log|x-6| = 2$$
$$\implies |x-6| = 10$$

Which will give you the resulting answer.

Another way to do it would be to just write:

$$\log(x^2-12x+36) = 2$$
$$\implies x^2 -12x+36 = 100$$

And solved the quadratic.

Comment: Thank you. You are a nice person 